# Jpa named query: how to get a list of column

Tags: java, jpa, entitymanager, named-query

I have an entity orderdetails, where a user can have many ordernames I want to get all the ordername by userid using jpa named query. I tried this

```
SELECT o.orderName FROM OrderDetails o WHERE o.userId=:userId;
```

Since the return type will be List in the resultset, I executed the query like this

```
getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("getOrderNamesByUserId", 
orderDetail.class).setParameter("userId", userId);
```

This obviously is not working. How can I get that query working? One way is to iterate the List but I wonder whether there is another way around?

Answer (score 0):

Well this is non-compiled code snippet, you could try the following approach.

```
@Override
public List<OrderDetails> findOrders(Long userId) {
        TypedQuery<OrderDetails> query = entityManager.createNamedQuery(
                "OrderDetails.getOrderNamesByUserId", OrderDetails.class);
        query.setParameter("userId", userId);
        List<OrderDetails> list = query.getResultList();
        return list;
    }
```

Comment: yes, this is obvious, but I need is List<String> (list of ordernames), not the list of type orderdetails (not List<OrderDetail)

Comment: @user3706166 Once you have in list, then you could retrieve using `toString()` method.

Comment: yes, I was wondering if there is any way to get the result on the fly..! just like normal query.

Comment: @user3706166 I didn't quite understand _result on the fly..! just like normal query_

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to select one column(ordername), use `getResultList()` method.

```
    Query query = getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("getOrderNamesByUserId", OrderDetail.class);
    query.setParameter("userId", userId);
    List<String> orderNameList = query.getResultList();
```

Comment: We cannot do this. Because,  query.getResultList() returns a resultlist of type List<OrderDetail>.

Comment: Check your query `SELECT o.orderName ..`. It is return a list of `OrderDetail`?.